# Is there a way to generate atoms dynamically in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is there a way to declare atoms dynamically in Elixir?

like `str = "aaa"` and we want to create an atom called `:aaa`.

Comment: `String.to_atom`?

Comment: If you think you need to dynamically create atoms, rest assured, you don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can.

However, you need to be careful as atoms are not garbage collected and there are limits to the amount of atoms you can have (the default limit is 1,048,576). It might seem like a lot, but if your app runs for a long time and you are dynamically generating atoms, you will eventually hit the limit.

It is *generally* considered a bad idea to dynamically generate them, and should normally be limited to atoms you know exist.

However, to answer your question. Yes.

#### Example:

```ex
iex(1)> str = "aaa"
"aaa"

iex(2)> String.to_atom(str)
:aaa

iex(3)> :foo
:foo

# Use `String.to_existing_atom/1` if you can.

iex(4)> String.to_existing_atom("foo")
:foo

iex(5)> String.to_existing_atom("bar")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("bar", :utf8)
```

Comment: So you can crash the process with `for x <- 1..1050000, do: String.to_atom Integer.to_string(x)`. Thanks.

Comment: @Shih-MinLee not only process but whole VM. That is the reason why in Phoenix params are strings not atoms as it would make your app vulnerable to DoS attacks.

Comment: Got it. Thanks that makes sense!